# How can I get LanguagesFractions data in different years?

Tags: warning-messages, data

[image]

I want to do that.
  But it failed.
  May I change my code? Or Where can I get these data?

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
CountryData["Japan", "LanguagesFractions"]
```

This is all the data available to Mathematica. I'm afraid that where to find random data is beyond the scope of this site. Perhaps scholar.google.com can be of some use - there may be academic papers on this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

Generally using `Entity` and friends will give you more control over the data. And in fact it does *appear* that this data will be possible to get in a `Dated` fashion:

```
EntityValue[
 EntityProperty["Country", "LanguagesFractions"],
 "QualifierValues"
 ]

{"Date" -> {}}
```

But in practice this fails:

```
EntityValue[
 Entity["Country", "Japan"],
 EntityProperty["Country", "LanguagesFractions", 
  {"Date" -> DateObject[{1980}]}
  ]
 ]

Missing["NotAvailable"]
```

This suggests one of two things a) I'm using the syntax incorrectly or b) the data is simply unavailable.

On the other hand you *can* figure out where they pulled this data from and try to get it for yourself:

```
EntityValue[
 Entity["Country", "Japan"],
 "LanguagesFractions",
 "Source"
 ]

{Entity["Source", "CIAFactbook"]}

Entity["Source", "CIAFactbook"]["URL"]
```

https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/